# groovy versus ivy

Tags: groovy, ivy

I notice that, by default, the groovy eclipse plugin sets up an ivy dependency.

This tantalizingly suggests that there's a way to declare dependencies for a groovy script and resolve them from a repo.

However, the web page at codehaus that describes groovy+ivy is just a page of dead links to a dead domain.

Comment: Is Google not working over there? -1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groovy has a handy @Grab annotation that allows including dependencies dynamically at runtime. It internally uses ivy and can access Ivy/Maven repositories. More information on that can be found here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape

One example from the site:

```
@Grab(group='org.springframework', module='spring', version='2.5.6')
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

Another option for ivy integration is at the build level. [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) the groovy based build system can also include dependencies as part of a build.